# Word for simple list of fixed choices

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the correct word for a fixed list of choices?

Something that appears in a select box in a computer application or as titles around a knob on a device. Like, music genre list in iTunes or equalizer presets on a guitar combo.

These are lists that would be held in a single-column database table. I would like to have an encompassing word for all such tables.

- Is it *codebook*? There is no encoding taking place.
- *dial*? Too much resembling an actual piece of hardware.
- *lookup table* may sound good, but there is no lookup. It is just a list of choices.

What word do software/database architects use to describe those? What is the label of a menu item in an administrative interface of an information system?

Answer (score 2):

When writing such code I refer to the displayed list as the *menu* (a term that you used in your question), and to the items within the list as *options*. Whether the options are selected from a menu displayed as static list, a dropbox list or as radiobuttons is of secondary interest.

Answer (score 0):

The general term is multiple choice.

As for a word that covers this in user interface design, I've come across the term drop box and list box.

I'm sure that there are others as designers have a way of representing the same functionality in a myriad kind of ways, and each with its own name.

For example, a checkbox.

Comment: To me, “drop box” and “list box” sound more as the user interface element than the values presented by them.